# What is difference between the KFP SDK v2, v2 namespace, and v2 compatible mode?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kfp

What is the difference between KFP SDK v2, the v2 namespace in KFP SDK v1, and v2 compatible mode?

Answer (score 3):

The KFP SDK has two major versions: [v1.8.x](https://pypi.org/project/kfp/1.8.14/) and [v2.x.x](https://pypi.org/project/kfp/2.0.0b5/) (in pre-release at the time of writing this).

**KFP SDK v2.x.x** compiles pipelines and components to IR YAML [[example](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/72aab0b5b82744ea0e3405aee353ee862fdfcf02/sdk/python/test_data/pipelines/pipeline_with_retry.yaml)], a *platform neutral* pipeline representation format. It can be run on the [KFP open source backend](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v2) or on other platforms, such as [Google Cloud Vertex AI Pipelines](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/introduction).

**KFP SDK v1.8.x**, by default, compiles pipelines and components to [Argo Workflow YAML](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/). Argo Workflow YAML is executed on Kubernetes and is *not platform neutral*.

KFP SDK v1.8.x provides two ways to author pipelines using v2 Python syntax:

**KFP SDK v2-compatible mode** is a feature in KFP SDK v1.8.x which permits using v2 Python authoring syntax within KFP SDK v1 but compiles to Argo Workflow YAML. v2-compatible mode is deprecated and should not be used.

The **KFP SDK v2 namespace** in KFP SDK v1.8.x (`from kfp.v2 import dsl, compiler`) permits using v2 Python authoring syntax within KFP SDK v1 and compiles to IR YAML [[usage example](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/blob/sdk/release-1.8/sdk/python/kfp/v2/compiler_cli_tests/test_data/pipeline_with_env.py)]. While this mode is not deprecated, users should prefer authoring IR YAML via the pre-released [KFP SDK v2.x.x](https://pypi.org/project/kfp/2.0.0b5/).